# Nodemon server perpetuality and runtime log issue

Tags: node.js, sails.js, forever, nodemon

I have a sailsjs app on AWS EC2, which I have been running till now using forever. I have two adantages using forever:

1) **Perpetuality:** I can use the CLI `forever start app.js` or `forever restart app.js` and then app starts running and keeps on running till I stop it with the command `forever stop app.js`. So, the app does not stop even when I close my terminal. The process keeps on running.

2) **Runtime Log:** I have a `.forever` directory that has a log file, while on real time records the server logs, and when I check the log using `tail -f file_name.log`, I get to see run time logs.

However there is a disadvantage: Every time I upload a new/modified server file, I have to restart the app manually. To get rid of this, I am switching from forever to nodemon.

From the documentation provided by Nodemon, I cant figure out how can I replicate the two advantages, as mentioned above, from Nodemon too. Will be a great help if anyone can guide me on how to start my nodejs app using nodemon so that it can keep running even after closing the terminal on my side, and how to watch runtime log of server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just my two cents.
I use `nodemon` daily while developing and I dont think its something you want to use in place of something like `forever`. Nodemon is used when developing, the software will detect when there has been a file change and restart the server but for deployment it should not be considered.
There is no need to change either because forever has this use case handled with the `--w` or `--watchDirectory` comand that will watch for file changes(It can be found [here on their readme](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever)).

Comment: Perfect, that makes sense, because live environment is not something tinkered frequently, and so forever is good for it. Thank you.

And just came to know [forever start -c nodemon app.js] makes both forever and nodemon work together.

Comment: But forever's official page states to use nodemon 

Comment: this was about 5 years ago @AbdulSaleem its probably changed since

Comment: For deploying node applications in a production environment, one can also look at pm2. It also automatically restarts the application in case of a crash as well. Maintains log files for the application as well. I use pm2 in production and nodemon during development.